# How to provision using maven

Tags: maven, war, provisioning

How can I use maven to provision a simple project? I want to provision a WAR file with jboss on a Linux server. I have the file saved in archiva.

I see that there is a maven provisioning plugin. I'd more just like to know how and what is required to happen so that when I use the plugin I'm not doing it blindly.

Comment: Take a deep look at http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin

Comment: Not sure what "maven provisioning plugin" you're talking about.

Comment: This plugin: http://mvnplugins.fusesource.org/maven/1.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-provision-plugin/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Cargo is a solution, as suggested in the comments, but from personal experience, I'd suggest
[`jboss-as-maven-plugin`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/), since it's easier to set up.

Cargo is the way to go if you need to deploy to multiple different types of servers.